# Why is this as it is (number of men twenty years old and over who were subject to military service, as censused in the Sinai Desert )?

Tags: number, shevatim-12-tribes, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

It is written in Parashah 34: B’midbar (In the desert) 1:1–4:20:

"20 The men twenty years old and over who were subject to military service were recorded by name, family and clan, starting with the descendants of Re’uven, Isra’el’s firstborn. Here are the totals:

21 Descendants of Re’uven   46,500

22-23 Descendants of Shim‘on    59,300

24-25 Descendants of Gad    45,650

26-27 Descendants of Y’hudah    74,600

28-29 Descendants of Yissakhar  54,400

30-31 Descendants of Z’vulun    57,400

32-33 Descendants of Efrayim    40,500

34-35 Descendants of M’nasheh   32,200

36-37 Descendants of Binyamin   35,400

38-39 Descendants of Dan    62,700

40-41 Descendants of Asher  41,500"

42-43 Descendants of Naftali    53,400

You see that all these numbers end in 0, and, if you ask me, this is not a coincidence, and it is not rounding (for example 35401 can be rounded to 35400), cause I believe that these are exact numbers. This is not (just) a numerology question but search for some deep reasons of why tribes had their men twenty years old and over who were subject to military service all as they are rounded to be multiples of 10 (or 50, if you want)?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the numbers aren't rounded?

Comment: @ba I see no reason of why they would be rounded. Is it hard to believe that they are as they are?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Not possible.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely for 12 random numbers to all end in 0. It is more unlikely for of 11 random numbers to end in 00 without rounding.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Right, I had course in probability theory a relatively long time ago, but am still (I hope), able to calculate that probability. This is not random at all, if you ask me.

Comment: .1^12 for all 0's. .01^12  for 11 00s plus 1 50

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you feel this isn’t a duplicate?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, if the numbers ended, respectively, in 19, 65, 23, 17, 25, 09, 81, 45, 28, 37, 11, and 60, the probability of that would also be .01^12.

Comment: any discrete set of numbers has the same probability but when I divide the numbers into two sets (zeros v. non zeros), if the numbers were random, I would expect only 1/10 of the numbers to be zeros but instead I got 0/12.